# How to write String monkeypatch method that will modify it

Tags: ruby, monkeypatching

I'd want to monkeypatch Ruby's String class by providing `shuffle` and `shuffle!` methods.

```
class String
  def shuffle
    self.split('').shuffle.join
  end
end
```

It returns a new string. How can I write a `shuffle!` method that modifies string instead of returning copy?

---

I tried to figure it out by myself but String's source code is in C in MRI.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can't assign to `self`, which is probably the first thing that comes to mind. However, there's a convenient method [`String#replace`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/String.html#method-i-replace), which, you know, replaces string's content.

```
class String
  def shuffle
    split('').shuffle.join
  end

  def shuffle!
    replace shuffle
  end
end

s = 'hello'
s.shuffle!
s # => "lhleo"
```